# How to perform a similar operation as AffineTransform.transform on Android?

Tags: android, matrix, android-canvas

```
public Point2D transform(Point2D ptSrc, Point2D ptDst)
```

> Transforms the specified ptSrc and stores the result in ptDst. If
>   ptDst is null, a new Point2D object is allocated and then the result
>   of the transformation is stored in this object. In either case, ptDst,
>   which contains the transformed point, is returned for convenience. If
>   ptSrc and ptDst are the same object, the input point is correctly
>   overwritten with the transformed point.

How do I perform a similar operation on Android? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Matrix.mapPoints`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#mapPoints%28float%5b%5d,%20float%5b%5d%29) class for this. For example:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix(orig);
m.preScale(scale, scale);
m.postTranslate(x, y);

float[] src = { 0.5, 0.3 };
float[] dst = new float[2];
m.mapPoints(dst, src);
//...
```