# Affine transform Android

Tags: android, opencv

I want to use AffineTransform in my Android application.
my app working with openCV and I have two Rect's (openCV object contains: x,y,width,height) each Rect describe image dimensions.
and I would like to use AffineTransform to see how one image will be present with other image Rectangle (dimensions).
my problem is that I don't know how to convert Rect to 3*3 Matrix, in order to use:

[How to perform a similar operation as AffineTransform.transform on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019469/how-to-perform-a-similar-operation-as-affinetransform-transform-on-android)

Thank's
David

Comment: you cannot convert Rect to Matrix, you can however compute the Matrix based on two Rects

Comment: Thank's. you have any sample code?

Comment: Matrix.setRectToRect()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affine transform is a real overkill if all you need is to transform image from one size to another. It will be much more simple to use [resize](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) function.

Edit (for first comment):
Sorry, I thought you are trying to transform image, not geometric data. Anyway, in your case you don't need full affine transform. All you need is scale x and scale y. Appropriate transformation matrix will be:

(sx, 0, 0)

(0, sy, 0)

(0,  0, 1)

Edit (for second comment):

```
sx = (double)rect1.width/rect2.width;
sy = (double)rect1.height/rect2.height;
double m[9] = {sx, 0, 0, 0, sy, 0, 0, 0, 1};
Mat transf(3, 3, CV_64F, m);
```

Comment: I want to know how some point of one image, will be places on image with different dimensions, so resize the image will not be helpful here.

Comment: Thank's, do you know how can I get these points if I have Rect only- and I need to convert it to 3*3?

Comment: Hi, what is Mat transf(3, 3, CV_64F, m); is it Android method? openCV?

Comment: OpenCV - yes. Android - no. I am using C++, and I don't know exactly how it should look like on Android. It should be pretty similar I suppose. Anyway I thought it would be better than nothing...

Comment: Sure Thank's I will look for conversion to Android